# C#/WPF: How to find the closest line breaks from the selection of a TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I have a `TextBox` `txtEditor`. I want to find the nearest line breaks and select it

**Example 1: With "no selection"**

suppose the selection/cursor is `*`

```
this is the 1st line of text
this is *the 2nd line of text
this is the 3rd line of text
```

I want to extend the selection such that the selection is now

```
this is the 1st line of text
*this is the 2nd line of text*
this is the 3rd line of text
```

**Example 2: With selection**

```
this is the 1st line of text
this is *the 2nd line* of text
this is the 3rd line of text
```

I want to extend the selection such that the selection is now

```
this is the 1st line of text
*this is the 2nd line of text*
this is the 3rd line of text
```

**Update: Possible solution**

I found a possible solution, wonder if anyone got a better solution?

```
string tmp = txtEditor.Text;
int selStart = txtEditor.SelectionStart;
int selLength = txtEditor.SelectionLength;
int newSelStart;
int newSelLength;

string tmp1 = tmp.Substring(0, selStart);
if (tmp1.LastIndexOf(Environment.NewLine) < 0)
{
    newSelStart = 0;
}
else
{
    newSelStart = tmp1.LastIndexOf(Environment.NewLine) + Environment.NewLine.Length;
}


tmp1 = tmp.Substring(selStart);
if (tmp1.IndexOf(Environment.NewLine) < 0)
{
    newSelLength = tmp.Length;
}
else
{
    newSelLength = tmp1.IndexOf(Environment.NewLine) + selStart - newSelStart;
}

txtEditor.SelectionStart = newSelStart;
txtEditor.SelectionLength = newSelLength;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, mostly the problem is that your code is somwhat bloated (and thus harder to read) and a lot less efficient than it needs to be.  Performance probably doesn't really matter in your case (those duplicate calls to `IndexOf` and `LastIndexOf` rub me the wrong way), but personally I'd rewrite your code like this:

```
string tmp = txtEditor.Text;
int selStart = txtEditor.SelectionStart;
int selLength = txtEditor.SelectionLength;

int newSelStart = tmp.LastIndexOf(Environment.NewLine, selStart);
if (newSelStart == -1)
    newSelStart = 0;

int newSelEnd = tmp.IndexOf(Environment.NewLine, selStart);
if (newSelEnd == -1)
    newSelEnd = tmp.Length;

txtEditor.SelectionStart = newSelStart;
txtEditor.SelectionLength = newSelEnd - newSelStart;
```